# unitary testing in doGet(request) - Google Apps Script

Tags: unit-testing, google-apps-script

I'm developing a simple google Script and publishing it as a web app.

The starting of my method is as follows:

```
function doGet(request) {

  var start = request.parameters.start;
  var end = request.parameters.end;

  if (isNaN(Number(start)))
    return generateError (3, start);
  if (isNaN(Number(end)))
    return generateError (4, end);

 /*
  * ...
  * lot of irrelevant stuff for current question
  * ...
  */

}
```

I want to add some basic unitary testing. I have it ready for secondary functions, but I'm not sure how to do it with the *doGet (request)* function.

At the present moment I'm using the following method:

```
function testDoGet(){
  var queryString = "?start=1&end=5";
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() + queryString;
  var options =
      {
        "method"  : "GET",   
        "followRedirects" : true,
        "muteHttpExceptions": true
      };

  Logger.log(url);
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(result);
```

But this does not allow me to debug, and also it requires that the code has been published (but is not executing the latest code), I would be interested in validate parameters received (for example)

Is there any way so we can simulate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can just call it directly and provide the parameters as an actual HTTP call would do, e.g.

```js
function testDoGet() {
  var requestMock = {
    parameters: {
      start: 1,
      end: 5
    }
  };
  Logger.log(requestMock);
  var result = doGet(requestMock);
  Logger.log(result);
}
```